# How can I specify folder for arguement to exec method in Java?

Tags: java, unix

So I have this simple code:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("ls");
```

which works fine. (pr input stream will give me the file names..)

However I want to make something like this work:

```
Process pr = rt.exec("~/ls");
```

I want to get the file names in the directory of the Home folder of the current logged in user.

What I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "~/ls": error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
```

Comment: *I want to get the file names in the directory of the Home folder of the current logged in user* -> I think that's rather `ls ~`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`~` is an expansion handled by the shell, Java does not know about it.

To get the home directory use the `java.home` property (with `System.getProperty`)

Note if you want to run a program in a specific working directory, use `ProcessBuilder` and call the `directory` method.

Answer (score 2):

When you run a program, is is not the same as running a shell to parse your command line unless you actually call the shell

```
exec("/bin/sh", "-c", "ls ~");
```

or

```
exec("ls", System.getProperty("user.home"));
```

Note: when you specify the directory at the start, you want to run the command in that directory, not pass the directory to a command as an argument.

e.g.

```
/bin/ls
```

means run the `ls` which is in the `/bin` directory (with no arguments)

```
ls /bin
```

mean pass `/bin` to the command `ls`